# iOS Multiview App

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to build a multiview app i.e. based on some gestures, new views are shown, removed etc.

I have found 3 ways to do so -

1. `[self.view insertSubview:newViewController.view atIndex:3];`
2. Using [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. Finally using modalViewController - `[self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`

First off, in second method, can I use this controller without `UINavigationTabBar`? I have a set of custom `UIView` objects which I want to push & pop from Screen. I dont want the ugly Apple's NavigationBar at top (or bottom). I will provide custom buttons based on which `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated]` should occur. Can this be possible?

Also, Which of these techniques is best? In terms of usage & code maintenance, memory usage etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of usage & code maintenance, memory usage etc., there's little doubt that `UINavigationController` is the best fit. It's been optimized for exactly the sort of thing you're doing. And because you push and pop `UIViewController`s from it (not just `UIView`s), views that are not currently displayed on screen can be automatically released to free up memory by the OS.

Can you use a navigation view without the bar across the top? I think maybe you should RTFM. Specifically, `-setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`

That said, `UINavigationController` is not particularly flexible at doing things it wasn't designed to do. In particular, it's opinionated about the transitions it uses to animate between view controllers on its stack.

You might have some luck pushing and popping sans animation (by passing `NO` to the `animated:` parameter of those methods), and having a delegate set up to handle `-navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`. You could in theory add a `CATransition` to the root view's animations there. But anything much more complicated than that (a view that tracks your finger while sliding on to the screen, etc.) and you'll probably have to write your own controller and manage your own views.

But you should still read Apple's *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS* and the `NSNavigationManager` specs until you grok them in their fullness. It'd be hard to find a better pattern to base your design around.

Answer (score 0):

Second one UINavigationController. And yes you can use your custom navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for the confirming about `UINavigationController`. Could you post some reasoning? Also, could you show me how to use `UINavigationController` internally? i.e. to switch around custom views controllers?

Comment: to add to this, I DO NOT want a navigation bar at all. when a new view is presented to the user, I wish to provide a "BACK" button which should do `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated]`. How is this possible?

Comment: Using UINavigationController its easy to navigate between multiple views hierarchically. You might be able to use the other options that you mentioned as well. But using UINavigationController is more logical way to navigate between multiple views. You can hide navigationBar - (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated and then add a Back button to your view and Button action would do [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];